# Openvpn TAP client different gateway than local network / How to allign

Tags: windows, openvpn

I have an OpenVPN client setup on my local accessible media server and it is mainly functioning as it should.

However, some LAN clients have problems with accessing the media server locally, as they try to connect to the TAP connections ip (10.8.2.10) instead of the server's actual lan ip (192.168.0.111).

What can I do to align the gateways or tell my clients to find the servers actual lan ip_

Media server with OpenVPN client is running windows
Local clients which need to access the media server are android clients and the like.

The router is running OpenWRT

IPconfig Tap adapter

```
       Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Windows Adapter V9
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-45-2F-41-74
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3863:63cf:9e1c:48d2%7(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.2.10(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, 11 March 2021 19.06.04
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Friday, 11 March 2022 19.06.03
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.2.254
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 302055237
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-24-8B-3E-A9-94-C6-91-10-EA-FF
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 103.86.96.100
                                       103.86.99.100
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Local ethernet adapter:

```
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 94-C6-91-10-EA-FF
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.111(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, 11 March 2021 19.05.53
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Monday, 18 April 2157 02.05.42
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```